# How to add an image inside a nvd3 bar chart?

Tags: jquery, d3.js, nvd3.js

I implemented a d3 bar chart in my project. However I now need to add a small image above each bar , and while click on the image, I need to redirect to a new page to show some more information. How can I achieve this?
 Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried? Did it not work and you get any errors? Could you give an example of your current implementation of a bar graph? (http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: i have created a public repository https://bitbucket.org/FaysalAhmed/nvd3_issue/src the code file is index.html , I need to add a small image (? mark images) above each bar so that user can click on that image and go to next page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this, you would need to select the elements that contain the bars and append the images to them. The image elements would be inside the anchor elements that specify the link targets. The code would look something like this.

```
svg.selectAll(".nv-bar")
   .append("a")
   .attr("xlink:href", newPage)
   .append("image")
   .attr("xlink:href", imageURL);
```

Note that you would need to adjust the position of the image to appear above the bar, i.e. something like `.attr("transform", "translate(0,-20)")` -- the exact values will depend on the size of your image.

Comment: Hi, I tried svg.selectAll(“.nv-bar”) it responded with [TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined] 
However writing d3.selectAll(“.nv-bar”) returning array. 
I tried the code you given but still not worked. I have uploaded my codes in https://bitbucket.org/FaysalAhmed/nvd3_issue/src/50dab0b6af3cdd474ecac94c7e0ff6d4265d6c42/index.html?at=master Hope it might help to understand the problem I am faceing.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail please? The code in the answer is really only a guideline -- you can't just copy and paste it. How is it not working?

Comment: The code I given in bitbucket is working and that is a example, true . Actually I am learning d3js and implementing it in a project and it is needed to add an image above each bar in a bar chart.   I need one example or an idea by which I can add an image above a bar in a bar chart. 

Comment: Here's a proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/9T8QZ/ You obviously need to adapt this to match your requirements.